# Jabber chat room user list missing?

Tags: empathy, jabber

I'm using Empathy to join a Jabber chat room. I have this setup on two Ubuntu machines, both running 12.04. To the right of the chat window should be a list of all the users currently in the chat room, but on one of my machines this list isn't there. How can I get it to appear?

Closing/reopening the chat room or rebooting don't make any difference. There are no menu or configuration options that I can see to control whether or not this list is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the user list was there, just resized down so much as to make it completely invisible. The fix was to mouseover the side of the window until the drag handle appeared, allowing me to expand it.

Comment: It seems so obvious when you put it like that. :D I have no idea why mine was resized to nothingness, as I can't imagine ever being able to do that by accident... but this got it back. Thanks! +1x2